# Passenger+nginx: Hosting a Rails application in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, subdirectory

I'm trying to deploy an application in a subdirectory `/a` under `www.myserver.com`, following the steps in the Passenger docs here:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

This seems to work, but the Rails routes are now all expecting the additional subdirectory `/a`, such that trying to access the root `www.myserver.com/a` gives me a RoutingError. I've tried setting `relative_url_root`, but that changes nothing. Do I need to add the prefix `/a` to every route in my routes file?

Comment: I know, I know, this is basic, but did you restart nginx after adding 'relative_url_root'?

Comment: btelles' instructions do work: in the end the problem was caused by undesired interaction between the gem 'reverse_proxy_fix' and Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm...all seems to have worked fine for me. Just tried it.

Are you sure you followed the **Nginx** instructions instead of the **Apache** instructions?

Make sure you do the soft link and change the 'root' application...the instructions say to make it the absolute path minus the 'public' part:

http {
    ...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name g.local;
    root /home/bernie/development/test;  <- forgot to change this the first time I tried
    passenger_enabled on;   
    passenger_base_uri /rails; 
}

...
```

}

Here's an image of the end result...no route modifications needed:

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/8898/32380822.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/8898/32380822.png)

Here are the Nginx instructions:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

Comment: If I understood his question he wants to have a rails app under the root app not change the path root app adding a superfluous directory name. For instance if you want to host several different apps under www.myhost.com like www.myhost.com/app1 www.myhost.com/app2 www.myhost.com/app3 which are all different rails apps. Your answer doesn't address that but instead unnecessarily adds an extra path to the root URL.